# Error make all for OpenCV3 - ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to install OpenCV3 but I keep getting this error:

```
usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.5m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython3.5m.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/build.make:224: recipe for target 'lib/python3/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/python3/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7226: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
```

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: How did you try to install?

Comment: I downloaded it from github and I am building it. I first downloaded the dependencies but still not working ...

Comment: I am following these steps: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide-on-Ubuntu-16.04 But I am not having nvidia so I am not having cuda

Comment: Usually I found it's easier to build with cmake as instructed on the official opencv website.

Comment: That doesnt work with me ...